# $f$ is integrable but has no indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, integration

Let $$f(x)=\cases{0,& $x\ne0$\cr 1, &$x=0.$}$$

Then $f$ is clearly integrable, yet has no antiderivative, on any interval containing $0,$ since any such antiderivative would have a constant value on each side of $0$ and have slope $1$ at $0$—an impossibility.

So does this mean that $f$ has no indefinite integral?

### EDIT

My understanding is that the indefinite integral of $f$ is the family of all the antiderivatives of $f,$ and conceptually requires some antiderivative to be defined on the entire domain. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, you are correct.

Comment: @IttayWeiss why should the indefinite Integral not exist? the integral is always zero, as a single ton is a null set

Comment: What's the difference between "antiderivative" and "indefinite integral"?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I interpret 'indefinite integral' the same as 'antiderivative'.

Comment: @julien The Fundamental Thm of Calculus, *simplified* Part I: If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $f=F'$ on $[a,b]$ for some $F$. Part II: If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $f=F'$ on $[a,b]$ for some $F$, then $\int_a^b =F(b)-F(a)$.  (There are a couple of variations of the FTC floating around.)   Part I guarantees that a continuous function on an interval has an antiderivative there, and Part II does not require that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @Ryan You're right. It's time to delete my comments...

Comment: @Ryan yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a matter of definitions. Usually an *antiderivative* of a function $f$ is any function whose derivative is $f$. The *indefinite integral* usually denotes *the set* of all antiderivatives.

Since every derivative satisfies the *intermediate values property*, your function $f$ cannot be a derivative and hence has no indefinite integral.

A different thing is the *integral function* which might be defined as a function $F$ such that 
$$
  \int_a^b f(x) dx = F(b)-F(a).
$$
This exists for all integrable functions.

The fundamental theorem of Calculus states that the two concepts agree for continuous functions.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that "indefinite integral" and "antiderivative" are technically synonymous. The function $f(x)=0$ has (particular) antiderivatives $f(x)=5$ and $f(x)=6$ but its *indefinite* integral is $f(x)=C$, where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

Comment: @Ryan: you are right, I corrected my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Just to supplement Emanuele’s answer. If $ I $ is an open subset of $ \mathbb{R} $, then some mathematicians define the indefinite integral of a function $ f: I \to \mathbb{R} $ as follows:
$$
\int f ~ d{x} \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \{ g \in {D^{1}}(I) ~|~ f = g' \}.
$$
Hence, taking the indefinite integral of $ f $ yields a **family of antiderivatives of $ f $**. If $ f $ has no antiderivative, then according to the definition above, we have
$$
\int f ~ d{x} = \varnothing.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to express $f$'s indefinite integral on its entire domain $\mathbb R$ runs into a technical problem at $x=0:$ $$\int f(x)\,\mathrm dx =\cases{C_1,& $x<0$\cr \mathbf{???}, &$x=0$\cr C_2,& $x>0$}.$$

No indefinite integral $\iff$ no antiderivative.

On the other hand, $f$ has an indefinite integral (and antiderivative) on every interval not containing $0.$